# How to highlight text displayed by includeHTML

Tags: r, shiny, highlight, dt

I am trying to create a reactive shiny app that can highlight text when I select an item(pair of words) from a datatable. I have got the datatable selection working. I am using `includeHTML()` function to include and display the text file.

Is it possible to highlight all occurrence of the item selected from the datable, in the text displayed by `includeHTML()`?

Comment: It's certainly possible. A reproducible example would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this for any arbitrary HTML file this probably won't work, but here is a pure R solution. You are probably better off with a javascript solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(mainPanel(
  DT::dataTableOutput("test"),
  htmlOutput("html")
)))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  words <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                      words = c("the", "hello", "world"))
  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({
    words
  }, selection = list(mode = "single", target = "row"))

  text <- "This is the hello world example for this problem."

  output$html <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$test_rows_selected))
      return(HTML(text))

    HTML(gsub(
      words$words[input$test_rows_selected],
      paste0("<mark>",
             words$words[input$test_rows_selected],
             "</mark>"),text ))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```